# How to change the Text value of a Telerik RichTextBox using c# and WinForms API

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, telerik, richtextbox

I am trying to set the text value of a RichTextBox by Telerik (ie. RadRichTextBox) to a value read from the database.

To set the value I tried the following which is not working "not setting the values"

```
InputDescription.Text = i._productDescription;
```

When I display the value of `i._productDescription` I do get results. So I am sure it is not empty/null and and the text box should have value.

How can I correctly set a text value to the RichTextBox?

Comment: Are you intentionally overwriting the values in each loop iteration? Try using the Lines property of the rtb instead of the Text property.

Comment: @Crowcoder The only reason for the foreach loop is because I am unable to get the records to work otherwise. I posted the getData method in my question. Also, How to use the Lines property of the rtb? InputDescription.Lines? this property does not exists

Comment: If your rtb is a System.Windows.Forms.RichtextBox then it does have a Lines property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Still not working. I am unable use the Lines properties. I remembered one thing that I am using the RadRichTextBox by Telerik. I don't know if that makes any different. Usually, the properties are the same. –  Mike 6 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Adding text in RadRichTextBox and RadRichTextEditor is done via importing, not with the Text property (although there is FR for this [link](http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/154/Feedback/Details/111956-add-radrichtextbox-init-the-content-using-text-property-with-support-of-html-f)).

Please refer to the following article which explains how you can import data in RadRichTextEditor: [Import/Export | UI for WinForms Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/richtexteditor-import-export.html).